# ffmpeg frame accurate seek with minimum delay

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a project where I need to extract part of a video near the end of video files and it needs to be frame accurate. I can extract my segment frame accurately now using '-vf' filter command and it works very well. The only problem is for large high-resolution files, the seek time ends up being 10X the time required for the extraction/encoding part. Is there any other or faster way to extract videos frame accurately?

The working command that I am currently using is below:

```
ffmpeg -i 'test_input.mp4' -vf 'trim=start_frame=134037:end_frame=135024,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS' -an -c:v libx264 -preset slow -f mp4 'test_output.mp4' -y 2>&1
```

Comment: Do you know the exact timestamp?

Comment: No I don't. I guess I can calculate it but I don't know how accurate it will be. Did you mean to propose this method?

ffmpeg -ss 01:02:30 -i "test_input.mp4" -to 01:04:30 .....